# Convert JSR303 JavaBean Validation exceptions to custom exceptions

Tags: java, aspectj, bean-validation, custom-exceptions

I have implemented the JSR303 JavaBean Validation in the Service layer of my web app (according to [this article](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2011/01/method-validation-with-hibernate.html)). Now I want to convert all validation exceptions (e.g. javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException) to my custom exception.

I created an Aspect that is invoked whenever an exception is thrown in the Service layer:

```
@Aspect
public class ExceptionConversionAspect {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="execution(* com.myexample.service.*.*(..))", throwing="e")
    public void convertServiceException(Exception e) {

        if (e instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
             // this is my custom exception
            throw new InvalidServiceInputException("The service inputs failed validation", e);
        }
    }
}
```

But my exception conversion aspect is not triggered when my service fails validation with ConstraintViolationException. I suspect this is because the validation exception is itself triggered by an Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class ValidateAspect {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    // Match any public methods in a class annotated with @AutoValidating
    @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @within(com.myexample.validator.annotation.Validate)")
    public Object validateMethodInvocation(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    // some code here
    ....
}
```

How do I chain my aspects in the correct order? ValidateAspect first, followed by ExceptionConversionAspect?

Comment: Maybe it would help to create aspect for validateMethodInvocation method - it would be triggered by exception thrown by that method or override ValidateAspect so it is throwing proper exception?

Answer (score 1):

Raul Bertone is almost right, but not quite. The logic must be reversed and the `ExceptionConversionAspect` must be the first in precedence.

Fully working sample for Java SE (I just emulate the Java EE exception):

**Helper classes:**

```java
package javax.validation;

public class ConstraintViolationException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8041265519275356912L;

    public ConstraintViolationException(String arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.myexample.validator.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Validate {}
```

```java
package com.myexample.service;

public class InvalidServiceInputException extends RuntimeException {
    public InvalidServiceInputException(String arg0, Throwable arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }
}
```

**Sample driver application:**

The driver application is annotated by `@Validate` and emulates a service - see package name. It loops through 10 method calls, catching exceptions and printing them to standard output so as to show that they are indeed converted as desired.

```java
package com.myexample.service;

import com.myexample.validator.annotation.Validate;

@Validate
public class Application {
    public void doSomething(int i) {
        System.out.printf("Doing something #%d%n", i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                application.doSomething(i + 1);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.out.println("  cause: " + e.getCause());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Aspects:**

The validation aspect randomly throws a `ConstraintViolationException` for demo purposes.

```java
package com.myexample.aspect;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class ValidateAspect {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    @Around("execution(public !static * *(..)) && @within(com.myexample.validator.annotation.Validate)")
    public Object validateMethodInvocation(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        if (RANDOM.nextBoolean())
            throw new ConstraintViolationException("uh-oh");
        return result;
    }
}
```

The exception conversion aspect has an additional `@DeclarePrecedence` annotation now.

```java
package com.myexample.aspect;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclarePrecedence;
import com.myexample.service.InvalidServiceInputException;

@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("ExceptionConversionAspect, *")
public class ExceptionConversionAspect {
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.myexample.service..*(..))", throwing = "e")
    public void convertServiceException(Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            throw new InvalidServiceInputException("The service inputs failed validation", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
Doing something #1
Doing something #2
com.myexample.service.InvalidServiceInputException: The service inputs failed validation
  cause: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: uh-oh
Doing something #3
com.myexample.service.InvalidServiceInputException: The service inputs failed validation
  cause: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: uh-oh
Doing something #4
Doing something #5
Doing something #6
com.myexample.service.InvalidServiceInputException: The service inputs failed validation
  cause: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: uh-oh
Doing something #7
Doing something #8
Doing something #9
Doing something #10
```

Answer (score 0):

When several aspects share a common joinpoint, you can manually set the execution order using the @DeclarePrecedence statement. In your case you can create a new aspect:

```
@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("ValidateAspect, ExceptionConversionAspect")
    public class SystemArchitecture {
        // ...
    }
```

If no precedence is specified, the execution order defaults to the rules defined [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-advice.html#advice-precedence)